# How can i store my buttons which are designed programatically?

Tags: android, listview, button, dynamic

I have a listView and in that listView every list row has a button, so when i click on the button a new button will be created in the main layout. So as many clicks i get those many buttons are getting created. But when i close my app and then open it again all those buttons disappear, so my ques is, how can i save those buttons which are created????

I am new in android programming plz help....

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.lllayout2);
```

//              LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//              ll.addView(button, 50,50);

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(activity);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
                    Button btnTag = new Button(activity);
                    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    btnTag.setText(text);
                    btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
                    row.addView(btnTag);
                }

                ll.addView(row);
            }
```

I am using this code on the onclicklistener in custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must save your newly created buttons in some sort of storage environment, example SQL Lite database, which is free and built in in android.

Comment: You can choose the storage area or environment that best suits you, I think SQL Lite database is the easiest and most flexible approach

Comment: so can i save a list<String> in internal storage?

Comment: Yes sure, you can save them one by one, or concatenate them into one string and save it as a one block

Comment: can i save the button in sql lite db or just the strings, i know this is a simple and an un professional quest, but still..?

Comment: mmm, I think you can serialize the button and save it, but i am not sure if this can be done

Comment: bro im really sry to disturb you again, but can you tell me how to make an sqlite db and add string to it...